# ?cdv parameter in ClientDependency framework breaks resource reference

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, client-dependency

In my ASP.NET MVC application I use [ClientDependency](http://clientdependency.codeplex.com/) framework to manage page dependencies of css and js.

For versioning client dependency framework adds query string paramter to a request. For example, the line in Razor:

```
Html.RequiresJs("http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/tiny/jquery.tools.min.js", 5);
```

results in a rendered html tag:

```
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/tiny/jquery.tools.min.js?cdv=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

While this request works:

```
http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/tiny/jquery.tools.min.js
```

The one with

```
http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/tiny/jquery.tools.min.js?cdv=1
```

doesn't.

How can I configure CD not to alter the request uri?